# xUnit - got stuck at how to print out anything from static method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xunit, specflow

Using MVS 2015/ Speckflow (2.4.1)/ xUnit (2.0.0)
Please help to printout anything from static method with xUnit framework:

```
namespace UnitTestProject2
{
    [Binding]
    public class SpecFlowHooks
    {

        private readonly ITestOutputHelper output;

        public SpecFlowHooks(ITestOutputHelper output)
        {
            this.output = output;
        }

        [BeforeFeature]
        public static void BeforeFeature()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~~ calling BeforeFeature");
        }

        [AfterFeature]
        public static void AfterFeature()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("~~~~~~~ calling AfterFeature");
        }

        [BeforeScenario]
        public void BeforeScenario()
        {
            output.WriteLine("~~~~~~~ calling BeforeScenario");
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void AfterScenario()
        {
            output.WriteLine("~~~~~~~ calling AfterScenario");
        }
    }
}
```

Result StandardOutput:

```
calling BeforeScenario
entered number: 50
entered number: 70
Add button pressed
Test passed
calling AfterScenario
```

As you can see, there's no output from static methods.

Comment: Try to add the ITestOutputHelper as parameter to the Before/AfterFeature static method. I think SpecFlow will inject the argument when calling the hook.

Comment: Hi, after updating methods to: 
        [BeforeFeature]
        public static void BeforeFeature(ITestOutputHelper output)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~~ calling BeforeFeature");
            output.WriteLine("~~~~~~~ calling BeforeFeature");
        }
  
got the following:
BoDi.ObjectContainerException : 
Interface cannot be resolved: 
Xunit.Abstractions.ITestOutputHelper
---- The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: 
FixtureData fixtureData

Comment: Sorry, you're right. There is no way to access the ITestOutputHelper in BeforeFeature. I think this is because xUnit does not provide it before the test (scenario) is running. You could search for a corresponding xUnit issue: how to access the ITestOutputHelper (or how to log in general) in an IClassFixture?